# Jersey (REST) Sub-resource CDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rest, jersey

I am working on an enterprise project that has an EJB module and a web project running on GlassFish v3.1, Weld v1.1 and Jersey. In the EJB I have defined an entity class `Manufacturer` and generated a session facade `ManufacturerFacade`.

In the web project I wish to expose `Manufacturer` instances through REST. To do so, I created the following resources:

The `ManufacturersResource` is a container resource that returns a list of all manufacturers stored in the database. It does so by injecting the `ManufacturerFacade` and calling the `findAll()` method. Abbreviated code:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/manufacturer")
public class ManufacturersResource {

    @Inject
    private ManufacturerFacade manufacturerFacade;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public List<Manufacturer> getManufacturers() {
        return manufacturerFacade.findAll();
    }
}
```

This resource also has a sub-resource:

```
@Path("{id}")
public ManufacturerResource getManufacturer(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return ManufacturerResource.getInstance(id, manufacturerFacade);
}
```

The `ManufacturerFacade` looks as follows:

```
public class ManufacturerResource {

    @Inject
    private ManufacturerFacade manufacturerFacade;

    private long id;

    private ManufacturerResource(String id) {
        this.id = Long.parseLong(id);
    }

    public static ManufacturerResource getInstance(String id,) {
        return new ManufacturerResource(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Manufacturer getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturerFacade.find(id);
    }
```

}

We are in a different class however, and the `ManufacturerResource` is not being instantiated by the framework and thus does not have the `ManufacturerFacade` injected.

I know I can simply pass the facade from the container resource (`ManufacturersResource`) to the item resource (`ManufacturerResource`) through the constructor but is it possible to somehow get DI working on them as well or is passing it through the constructor a perfectly fine solution here?

Thanks!

Comment: I feel the class `ManufacturersResource` would be clearer named as `ManufacturersResourceController`.

Comment: You are right. I am just getting my feet wet in REST so I have not yet been refactoring, but I will. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to use ResourceContext for this and pass the id using a setter. Please file a bug if it does not work (http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY).

```
@Context
private ResourceContext resourceContext;

@Path("{id}")
public ManufacturerResource getManufacturer(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    ManufacturerResource r = resourceContext.getResource(ManufacturerResource.class);
    r.setId(id);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks a million! That is working flawlessly. I should add that the item (`ManufacturerResource`) had to be `@RequestScoped` as well to get it working, but it is now!