# Can I use CDI to @Inject a class in Jersey 1.x?

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish-3, cdi, jersey-1.0

I think I'm asking this question but for Jersey 1.x: [Dependency injection with Jersey 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216759/dependency-injection-with-jersey-2-0)

I'm using Glassfish 3, CDI and Jersey 1.x.  I have a `@WebService` that is injecting a class like this:

```
@Inject
Foo foo;
```

I've tested this in the `@WebService` and it works.  But the same line of code in my Jersey resource throws a NPE when it tries to use `foo`.  I think Jersey 1.x is ignoring the CDI annotations.  How can I get dependency injection working like it does in my `@WebService`?

`Foo` is a pojo and my web.xml is using the ServletContainer:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

---

I've found [some help here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456918/61624).  The problem is my `Foo` `@Inject`s its own beans (they're actually EJBs that come from a class with `@Provides` in it).  `resourceContext.getResource(Foo.class);` returns an instance of `Foo`, but `foo`'s `@Inject`ed fields are null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [an article](http://coders-kitchen.com/2013/03/29/tutorial-how-to-use-jax-rs-and-cdi-together/) that explains how to do this:

> The problem here is, that CDI isn’t in place to instantiate the dependency.
>   Their[sic] are two solutions for this problem:
>
> 1. Let CDI instantiate the dependency, but let Jersey managed it
>      This can be achived using `@ManagedBean` and a Jersey specific annotation.
> 2. Let CDI instantiate the dependency and let CDI manage it.
>      This can be achieved using `@RequestScoped` or other CDI specific annotations.

I chose the first option and put the `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` annotation on my resource.  [Here's an example](https://github.com/coders-kitchen/GreetMeWithJaxRSAndCDI/blob/master/src/main/java/com/coderskitchen/thegreeter/rest/Greeter.java):

```
package com.coderskitchen.thegreeter.rest;

import com.coderskitchen.thegreeter.greetings.GreetingService;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("/greet")
@ManagedBean
public class Greeter {
    @Inject
    GreetingService gs;
    @GET
    @Path("{name}")
    public String greetSomeone(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return gs.greetSomeone(name);
    }
}
```

* Also I found this official article, which actually isn't as useful: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs-advanced004.htm