# @Inject is not working in JAX-RS resource

Tags: maven, tomcat, jax-rs, cdi

I'm trying to use @Inject with JAX-RS.  My problem is that @Inject is only working in Servlets. In JAX-RS resources I'm getting nullpointer and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. My code looks like this:

Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- JBoss/Weld Refrence Implementation for CDI on a Servlet Container -->
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Provided by Tomcat, but needed for compilation -->
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Twitter API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>`
```

web.xml contains:

`<resource-env-ref>
        <!-- Enable Weld CDI, also needs META-INF/context.xml entry -->
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>`

working class:

```
package com.tinf15B2.webengeneering.boundary;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.tinf15B2.webengeneering.facade.Control;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class StartUpService implements ServletContextListener {

@Inject
private Control serviceController;

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    serviceController.stopTweetListener();
    log.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Service was closed");
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    serviceController.startTweetListener();
    log.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Service started");
}
}
```

serviceController.startTweetListener() and serviceController.stopTweetListener() work. There's no nullpointer.

not working class:

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.tinf15B2.webengeneering.facade.Control;

@Path("/")
public class HashTagStatistic {

    @Inject
    private Control serviceController;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response getStartingPage()
    {
        String output = "<h1>Hello World!<h1>" +
                "<p>RESTful Service is running ... <br>Ping @ " + new Date().toString() + "</p<br>";
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }   

    @Path("resources/hashtagstatistic")
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response getHashTagStatisticAsHtml(){
        return Response //
                .status(200) //
                .entity(serviceController.getDatabaseContent()) //
                .build();
    }
}
```

But when I try to call serviceController.getDatabaseContent() in this class I get a nullpointer.

Error-Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.tinf15B2.webengeneering.boundary.HashTagStatistic.getHashTagStatisticAsHtml(HashTagStatistic.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I have no idead what's wrong. Would be awesome if anyone has a solution =)

Thank you!

Comment: @BalusC You've marked this as duplicate of Jersey2 (groupId `org.glassfish.jersey`) question, however original poster uses Jersey1 (groupId `com.sun.jersey`). A better link would've been this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22994058/2492865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HashTagStatistic` is a JAX-RS resource. JAX-RS resources have their own lifecycle handled by the JAX-RS implementation itself, and CDI is not part of this lifecycle. However, many JAX-RS implementations provide a CDI/JAX-RS bridge that you can enable.

You seem to be using Jersey 1 as your JAX-RS implementation, so this should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22995780/2492865

If you're considering about upgrading to Jersey 2, read this documentation: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/cdi.support.html